# Three divs side by side but no auto margin between them

Tags: html, css

I have 4 rows of three divs side by side in a container. The whole thing is supposed to be responsive so it auto-adjusts to variable container widths, i.e. for desktop three divs, for tablets two divs next to eachother and for smartphones, one div alone.
I thought that when setting the width at 30% for each div, the remaining 10% would be split between the two divs in terms of the margin, i.e. 5% margin between each div. But now I got the full 10% margin to the right of my third div, meaning all divs are glued together. How to get 2 x 5% margin BETWEEN the divs (margin-right:5% doesnt work)?

```css
.aaa {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
 margin-top:30px;
 padding:2px 25px 2px 25px;
 text-align:center;
 float:left;
 width:30%;
 height:239px;
    background-color:blue;
}

.bbb {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
 margin-top:30px;
 padding:2px 25px 2px 25px;
 text-align:center;
 float:left;
 width:30%;
 height:239px;
    background-color:grey;
}

.ccc {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
 margin-top:30px;
 padding:2px 25px 2px 25px;
 text-align:center;
 float:left;
 width:30%;
 height:239px;
    background-color:green
}

.ddd {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
 margin-top:30px;
 padding:2px 25px 2px 25px;
 text-align:center;
 float:left;
 width:30%;
 height:239px;
    background-color:yellow
}

.eee {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
 margin-top:30px;
 padding:2px 25px 2px 25px;
 text-align:center;
 float:left;
 width:30%;
 height:239px;
    background-color:red
}

.fff {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
 margin-top:30px;
 padding:2px 25px 2px 25px;
 text-align:center;
 float:left;
 width:30%;
 height:239px;
    background-color:black
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="aaa"><a href="#"><h1>aaa</h1></a></div>
<div class="bbb"><a href="#"><h1>bbb</h1></a></div>
<div class="ccc"><a href="#"><h1>ccc</h1></a></div>
<div class="ddd"><a href="#"><h1>ddd</h1></a></div>
<div class="eee"><a href="#"><h1>eee</h1></a></div>
<div class="fff"><a href="#"><h1>fff</h1></a></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you're using `box-sizing` so that the `padding` is being calculated properly.  You'll also likely want to utilize a media query in order to achieve your goal of their being fewer side-by-side elements on smaller screens.

https://jsfiddle.net/a6ry5m7v/

There are certainly more modern approaches (such as `flex` containers) but based on your original comments this seems to be the approach you were expecting